# Picture taken in portrait mode rotates

Tags: android, camera

> ```
>          Uri selectedImage = outputFileUri;
>                      InputStream imageStream =getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
>                      try
>                      {
>                          BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>                          bounds.inJustDecodeBounds=true;                                                      BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, AddStoreActivity.this), bounds);
>                          BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>                          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, AddStoreActivity.this), opts);
>                          ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, AddStoreActivity.this));
>                          String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
>                          int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;   
>                          int rotationAngle = 0;
>                          if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
>                          if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
>                          if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;
>                          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
>                          matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
>                          Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth, bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);
>                          bitmap2 = rotatedBitmap;//BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
>                      }
>                      catch(Exception ef)
>                      {
>                          bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
>                      }
> ```

Very simple, when in my android app i open camera..and take picture in portrait mode. i get the picture back rotated. how can i solve such issue?the above work i have done had no influence.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code

```
 matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
 Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth, bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);
```

with this

```
matrix.postRotate(rotationAngle);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Have you logged your code? Is it successfully getting through the whole process? I can't think of what else it would be. I have a block of very similar code working for me.

Comment: rotationAngle is always 0

Comment: And is orientString "0" as well?